How to make gas bbq ready for cooking after a long non use
I have a gas bbq which I haven’t used in 3 years and today I turned it on to see if it works and to my surprise it does. Now it has been filled with webs and other stuff to I turned it on.
What should I do to make it germs and bacteria free?
Generally we make something hot to make germs go away. Is that same for bbq as well?


What should I do to make it germs and bacteria free?
Generally we make something hot to make germs go away. Is that same for bbq as well?

Considering that water boils at 212°F and would be considered drinking-safe in regard to pathogens then I would say you've killed everything and degraded pathogen-produced toxins by the time you hit 500°F.
To note, grills aren't usually designed to run at 500°F for too long. It could cause a fire if you leave it at that temp. Read your manual to be certain.
Practically speaking you need to ensure your grill is in good working condition:

Check for gas leaks
Check the burners for clogs; small bugs and spider webs can cause flash-back
Clean the heat shields
Empty the grease trap
Clean the base of the grill beneath the burners
Remove and large debris
Burn off the spider webs and other small debris
Clean the grates from old food and rust
Lubricate the grates with oil; think of "seasoning" cast iron


I do not have manual. Can you recommeded me some general manual which tell everything about bbq and temperature?

@localhost Sure, just about any grill manual would suffice assuming the grill matches your BTU specs and is of similar quality. This Nexgrill model specifies 500-600 pre-heat for 10-15 minutes and also has a bunch of relevant safety information; https://images.thdstatic.com/catalog/pdfImages/e2/e23f1f0e-96ba-4f1f-8d5c-eb02843bfc2e.pdf

Germs/bacteria are not a concern and are killed by the heat. Always pre-heat your grill/bbq to smoke/burn off old food and oils, allow easy cleaning with a steel grill brush, and allowing new vegetable oils to be applied to the grates before each use.
Even without the heat, most germs and bacteria do very poorly in dry conditions for more than a few days to a few weeks.
It would also be a good idea to spray soapy water on the gas hose connections and regulator to verify no leaks.

Dismantle and clean it to the best of your ability using water, detergent and grease remover.
Use a steel brush to remove rust, especially from the grates.
If there's a flexible gas pipe replace it, then CHECK THE GAS LINES for leakage, breakage, for example using soapy water, or blockage (spider webs can do that).
Use cooking oil to oil the grates, then light the grill on high temperature for around 30 minutes or until it stops smoking.
You should be ready to go now.

While I get where you're coming from, how do you check for hose blockages using soapy water? :)

@SeanDuggan, if a hose is blocked, it won't be blowing soap bubbles at the outlet.

Although, arguably, a hose without leaks wouldn't be generating bubbles either. :-D No worries, just wasn't certain if it was a case of a dangling modifier.

@SeanDuggan you pour soapy water on one side and check if they come out on the other side (joking, I edited the sentence for clarity)

It is not safe to use steel brushes on the barbeque grill -- there is a risk of ingestion of the wires.  https://x.com/USCPSC/status/1520139268227833856

@DavidMcKee this is interesting! although it is not so relevant in the context of the question- this is a once in a lifetime cleaning. Steel brushes are better than nylon ones on tough dirt, and you can, and should, finish up cleaning afterwards with an oily rag or paper.

Also check the mechanical - make sure the stand/frame is still sound and that the whole thing is on a secure footing.
You wouldn't want a bolt or caster or leg to fail while you're cooking potentially dropping the cooker or making it fall over.   Rust is insidious, specially if it was stored outside for 3 years.

One thing to be extremely cautious of when cleaning a grill is wires coming off a wire brush -- use a nylon brush or a ball of aluminium foil.

source: https://x.com/USCPSC/status/1520139268227833856
